# Delphi: Using TextHint in a multiline text component such as TMemo or TRichEdit

Tags: delphi

TextHint is the TEdit property which let's you display a greyed text hint inside the textbox, when the textbox is empty.

I want to place the same kind of hint in a TMemo, or TRichEdit, since the TEdit component does not allow multiline.

How can I use a TextHint inside a multiline text control in Delphi?
The TextHint property actually exists in TMemo and TrichEdit components, but it seems to have no effect.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `TextHint` is implemented in `TCustomEdit`, which `TEdit`, `TMemo`, and `TRichEdit` all derive from.  But it is only exposed as `published` in `TEdit`, since that is the only control of the 3 that can actually use it. It should have been declared as `protected` in `TCustomEdit`, but instead it is declared as `public`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

The `TextHint` property is implemented using the [`EM_SETCUEBANNER` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb761639(v=vs.85).aspx).  Windows itself simply does not support that message on those UI controls:

> You cannot set a cue banner on a multiline edit control or on a rich
>   edit control.

Comment: True, but you can subclass the controls to handle painting manually, and so you could just draw your own banner text when the control is empty.

Comment: I have a feeling they may have made it `public` on purpose, with the *hopes* that some day in the future, Microsoft would introduce the same on those other controls.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is almost six years old, but this answer may be useful for others.

You can simulate a `TextHint` on a `TMemo` by putting a `TEdit` on top of the `TMemo`. Set TEdit `BorderStyle := bsNone`. Assign the TextHint to the TEdit. Add (the same) OnEnter event to both the `TMemo` and the `TEdit` that sets `TEdit` Visible to false (`MyTextEdit.Visible := false`) and moves focus to the `TMemo` (`MyMemo.SetFocus`). Set an OnExit event on the `TMemo` as follows:

```
MyEdit.Visible := (MyMemo.Text = '');
```

Everywhere where you assign text to the TMemo, make sure to also update `MyEdit.Visible` (`MyEdit.Visible := (MyMemo.Text = '')`).